# Is it possible to filter internet access on a mobile phone with a 3/4G connection with a proxy server?

Tags: mobile, squid

If you were to put a pfSense Squid Proxy Server with Squid Guardian on a DMZ and then point a cellphone with a 3/4G connection at it for SSL and HTTP with a self-signed CA certificate installed on it; assuming you have control of the phone, would it be possible to point it at the proxy server and keep it there?  I realize a transparent proxy is impossible in this case, but assuming you have a static IP or dynamic DNS address it would seem this is possible but I'm not sure.

Comment: How would you be able to point 3/4G connection to your filter (assuming you don't work for the ISP)?

Comment: @DKNUCKLES If it's on the DMZ if it has a public IP address or dynamic DNS then it should be accessible from the data connection...I guess...

Comment: @DKNUCKLES you know a 3G/4G data connection instead of wifi.

Comment: My Android allows setting up a VPN when on 3G/4G. I don't see why that mechanism couldn't be used to function as a proxy as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using a proxy server, it is just that a proxy. Everything will be forced to go through it, whether it is wired, wireless, 2G, 3G, 4G, LTE. The browser is configured to do the following:

```
phone (browser) --> go to Yahoo.com --> through this proxy (1.2.3.4)
proxy --> Internet --> I need this page
Yahoo --> Proxy <--> phone
```

The connection (wireless/wired/mobile) does not make a difference, all your phone would know that in order for it to get to the web, it needs to use this proxy. You will need to ensure the proxy server is always up otherwise no pages would be server.

Comment: Okay great!  But is it possible to lock down the settings on a phone?   I guess I'd have to ask another question about that.

Comment: @leeand00 I am not aware of the specifics, this may help you though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225156/override-or-disable-settings-menu if you're using an Android

Comment: @leeand00, +1 for understanding the benefit of separated questions!